# How do I build and implement a SearchClient in my android app using java?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-android-sdk

I am trying to build a cognitive search client using Microsoft azure cognitive search to query my indexer which has already indexed my data on the azure portal. What could possibly be the problem? is there an error with the compatibility of the dependencies and the android API level?

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.hiddeneye'
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hiddeneye"
        minSdk 26

        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/INDEX.LIST', 'META-INF/NOTICE.md', 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties', 'META-INF/LICENSE.md']
        }
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

//  Azure blob storage
    implementation 'com.azure.android:azure-core:1.0.0-beta.12'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.azure.android:azure-storage-android:2.0.0@aar'

//  Azure Cogntive Search
    implementation 'com.azure:azure-search-documents:11.5.5'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.3'
```

}

the method that does my search. I am doing it in an async method as that was what worked for me to take the data from my azure blob storage. I have already successfully created an indexer and an index on the azure portal itself. Queries can also be made on the azure portal so I want to link it up with my android app.

```
    public void searchVideos(String searchQuery) {
        System.out.println("search method block");
        Executor serialExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        serialExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("run method block");
                try {
                    System.out.println("client builder block");

                    searchClient = new SearchClientBuilder()
                            .endpoint(endpoint)
                            .credential(adminKey)
                            .indexName(indexName)
                            .buildClient();

                    System.out.println("search options block");
                    SearchOptions options = new SearchOptions();
                    options.setIncludeTotalCount(true);
                    options.setFilter("");
                    options.setOrderBy("");
                    options.setSelect("videoPath", "age");

                    System.out.println("search results block");
                    SearchPagedIterable results = searchClient.search(searchQuery, options, Context.NONE);

                    System.out.println("search items block");
                    List<VideoAttribute> items = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (SearchResult result : results) {
                        VideoAttribute item = result.getDocument(VideoAttribute.class);
                        items.add(item);
                    }
                    System.out.println(items.get(1));

                    videoAttributesLiveData.postValue(items);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

the createView method that calls the search method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        CognitiveSearchRepository searchRepository = new CognitiveSearchRepository();
        searchRepository.searchVideos("*");
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    }
```

this is the runtime error I got when I try to run my application

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.azure.core.implementation.ReflectionUtils.getLookupToUse(ReflectionUtils.java:119)
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.getDefaultConstructor(ExpandableStringEnum.java:88)
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.$r8$lambda$SMtq8BJfA6t_qJk1WfhslLPTCwc(Unknown Source:0)
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.apply(Unknown Source:2)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1710)
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.fromString(ExpandableStringEnum.java:68)
at com.azure.core.http.HttpHeaderName.fromString(HttpHeaderName.java:60)
at com.azure.core.http.HttpHeaderName.(HttpHeaderName.java:88)
at com.azure.core.http.HttpHeaderName.fromString(HttpHeaderName.java:56)
at com.azure.core.http.policy.RequestIdPolicy.(RequestIdPolicy.java:33)
at com.azure.search.documents.implementation.util.Utility.buildHttpPipeline(Utility.java:130)
at com.azure.search.documents.SearchClientBuilder.getHttpPipeline(SearchClientBuilder.java:203)
at com.azure.search.documents.SearchClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(SearchClientBuilder.java:175)
at com.azure.search.documents.SearchClientBuilder.buildClient(SearchClientBuilder.java:153)
at com.example.hiddeneye.Repository.CognitiveSearchRepository$1.run(CognitiveSearchRepository.java:51)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to use package-private MethodHandles.Lookup constructor.
at com.azure.core.implementation.ReflectionUtils.(ReflectionUtils.java:84)
at com.azure.core.implementation.ReflectionUtils.getLookupToUse(ReflectionUtils.java:119) 
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.getDefaultConstructor(ExpandableStringEnum.java:88) 
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.$r8$lambda$SMtq8BJfA6t_qJk1WfhslLPTCwc(Unknown Source:0) 
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.apply(Unknown Source:2) 
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1710) 
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.fromString(ExpandableStringEnum.java:68) 
at com.azure.core.http.HttpHeaderName.fromString(HttpHeaderName.java:60) 
at com.azure.core.http.HttpHeaderName.(HttpHeaderName.java:88) 
at com.azure.core.http.HttpHeaderName.fromString(HttpHeaderName.java:56) 
at com.azure.core.http.policy.RequestIdPolicy.(RequestIdPolicy.java:33) 
at com.azure.search.documents.implementation.util.Utility.buildHttpPipeline(Utility.java:130) 
at com.azure.search.documents.SearchClientBuilder.getHttpPipeline(SearchClientBuilder.java:203) 
at com.azure.search.documents.SearchClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(SearchClientBuilder.java:175) 
at com.azure.search.documents.SearchClientBuilder.buildClient(SearchClientBuilder.java:153) 
at com.example.hiddeneye.Repository.CognitiveSearchRepository$1.run(CognitiveSearchRepository.java:51) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup. [class java.lang.Class]
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2363)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2201)
at com.azure.core.implementation.ReflectionUtils.(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
at com.azure.core.implementation.ReflectionUtils.getLookupToUse(ReflectionUtils.java:119) 
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.getDefaultConstructor(ExpandableStringEnum.java:88) 
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.$r8$lambda$SMtq8BJfA6t_qJk1WfhslLPTCwc(Unknown Source:0) 
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.apply(Unknown Source:2) 
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1710) 
at com.azure.core.util.ExpandableStringEnum.fromString(ExpandableStringEnum.java:68) 
at com.azure.core.http.HttpHeaderName.fromString(HttpHeaderName.java:60) 
at com.azure.core.http.HttpHeaderName.(HttpHeaderName.java:88) 
at com.azure.core.http.HttpHeaderName.fromString(HttpHeaderName.java:56) 
at com.azure.core.http.policy.RequestIdPolicy.(RequestIdPolicy.java:33) 
at com.azure.search.documents.implementation.util.Utility.buildHttpPipeline(Utility.java:130) 
at com.azure.search.documents.SearchClientBuilder.getHttpPipeline(SearchClientBuilder.java:203) 
at com.azure.search.documents.SearchClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(SearchClientBuilder.java:175) 
at com.azure.search.documents.SearchClientBuilder.buildClient(SearchClientBuilder.java:153) 
at com.example.hiddeneye.Repository.CognitiveSearchRepository$1.run(CognitiveSearchRepository.java:51)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've confirmed with Azure SDK team that there is no guarantee that Java SDKs will work for Android development, nor support is offered to make them work. I am sorry about this. Perhaps someone in the community may be able to assist in this post for this purpose, if possible to make it work.

Comment: @GiaMondragon-MSFT, Hi Gia, thank you for your response. Would it be a good idea if I use the Java SDK for azure search to do up a web backend and deploy that to azure app services. Afterwards, I will connect my android app to the web backend with RESTful endpoints for the search to be done there instead. Is this a possible alternative?

Comment: You're welcome. It sounds like a viable workaround since you won't be accessing directly Azure search from Android but from your Azure app (and this is the recommended approach).